# Google Analytics custom metric not showing up

Tags: ios, sdk, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an iOS application which sends a bunch of tracked parameters to GA (Google Analytics) API which I can then see and interpret. Most of my code now works using snippets like:

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action" action:@"button_press" label:@"email_share" value:nil] build]];
```

Which are nice but what if I want to send custom metrics over - such as user ID or similar? How do I do that? I'm not an expert in GA so please explain it to me.

I want these custom variables to pop up in the custom metrics section (see the picture). How do I do that? I have read that they have to be custom since I will send some unique IDs over with them. Kinda like personalized tracking.

[image]

The GA SDK version is v3.0 and I have tried doing it the way [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets) does it. But they are not showing in there. Where should they pop up (since I didn't see them anywhere).

So the main question is how to send custom tracking values (user IDs) via GAI SDK to see them in here under the Custom variables?

**EDIT:**
After configuring a custom dimension in the web interface I have come across [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets-overview) on which I choose "iOS SDK" and am now trying to get a value across using this snippet:

```
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:@"Test"];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Login screen"];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:@"Username" forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
```

But I still cant see the value. Any clues?

Cheers, Jan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you set up the custom metric via the [Google Analytics web interface](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827)? This is where you'll get your metric index and where you set the scope.

Comment: Ok thanks for the hint. I have done the setup part on the web interface now and am now submitting the value via a snippet which I have provided in the edited question (see question). But the value is still not visible. I do see a new screen appear but no value for that dimension. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't found a way to look at custom dimensions without creating a custom report. Create a custom report and select your custom dimension as your dimension and throw in some metrics.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did to make custom dimensions work:

on app initialization, after all stadard GA inits, i put these lines:

```
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1] value:sCV1];
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2] value:sCV2];
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3] value:sCV3];
[tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:4] value:sCV4];

//these were the lines I was missing

[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:sCV1 forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:sCV2 forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2]] build]];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:sCV3 forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3]] build]];
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] set:sCV4 forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:4]] build]];
```

this only needs to be sent upon initialization if you don't need to change the values.

then you should be able to use custom dimensions in your reports/queries successfully, using standard GAITracker send method.